# Repeated sequence of bytes

Tags: byte, sequence

I am trying to find largest repeated sequence of bytes, but can not find solution. Will be gratefull for any help, prefereably on java.

Comment: four for() cycles and two if, and it is not working. I understand, i have to find some algorithm, but the best solution is not coming, yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is realy interesting. Should to build matrix from the bytes. Diagonal of this matrix and will be largest repeated sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can compare bytes with:

```
Java.lang.Byte.equals()
```

And you can compare arrays of bytes with :

```
java.util.Arrays.equals()
```

Without going into exact implementation, these should do all the dirty work for you.

Edit: You're not making your question clear at all. Nonetheless, this is what I was trying to describe to you. If this is not what you're after, then I have no idea...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] ba1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        byte[] ba2 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        byte[] ba3 = {1,2,9,4,5};

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(ba1, ba2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(ba1, ba3));

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

            Byte b1 = ba1[i];
            Byte b2 = ba3[i];

            System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I not need to compare bytes or arrays, i need to find largest repeated sequence in the bytes array

Comment: I have some bytes array new Byte[]{1, 24, 54, 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5,8, 24, 54,1, 6, 7}. And i want to find largest repeated sequence, here it is 24, 54, 1

Comment: The example above gives you all the tools you need. With a few loops and counters you should be able to come up with a solution. I'm not going to just give you an answer, but if you make an attempt and show the code, I will help you figure it out.

Comment: To give you a head start, try: for each x in array, check all other elements for match. If x == y, check if x+1 == y+1, if x+2 == y+2, etc... Keep track of the longest sequence you find.